# Installing New Kernel with apt

Tags: 14.04, apt, kernel

I am trying to install **Multipath TCP** kernel on my ubuntu machine following the documentation at [this link](http://multipath-tcp.org/pmwiki.php/Users/AptRepository).

> **Step 1:** Add the gpg-apt-key
>
> `wget -q -O - http://multipath-tcp.org/mptcp.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -`
>
> **Step 2:** Then add a new software repository in the new file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mptcp.list` with the following line:
>
> On a Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) for the newest v0.89-release:
> `deb http://multipath-tcp.org/repos/apt/debian trusty main`

But after step 1 there is no `mptcp.list` file created.

Is it some version issue or I need to boot again?  What could be the causes ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file will not be created automatically in this way.

Create a file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mptcp.list
```

and add the line

```
deb http://multipath-tcp.org/repos/apt/debian trusty main
```

Update the repositories

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and install your package.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-mptcp
```

---

And I quote [@ThomasW.](https://askubuntu.com/users/10616/thomas-w):

> Lets clarify this a little - the instructions that are posed by the
>   upstream source (multipath TCP) are implying that the user doing these
>   commands and tasks has ample understanding of the Command Line and the
>   package management system to know that the file is not automatically
>   created, and that the end user/admin has to create the file and such.

Comment: Lets clarify this a little - the instructions that are posed by the upstream source (multipath TCP) are implying that the user doing these commands and tasks has ample understanding of the Command Line and the package management system to know that the file is not automatically created, and that the end user/admin has to create the file and such.  Hence why it's not created.

Comment: @A.B. is mptcp.list a binary file . i see a mptcp.list.save file, i can't open it.

Comment: No, it's plain text. And you need `sudo` to open and edit the file.

Comment: And `mptcp.list.save` is a backup file.

Comment: @A.B. Thanks a lot. I can't still see mptcp.list in the file although .save is there. for other files both .list and .save are there.

Comment: @A.B. Now it says E: Unable to locate package linux-mptcp
I don't see the .list file only .save is there.

Comment: @ThomasW. It says E: Unable to locate package linux-mptcp
I followed the steps, now I guess it is not trivial, maybe ?

Comment: Common, follow my instructions and create the file.

Comment: @edbale Reread this answer, and you will see that you have to ***create the `.list` file yourself***, then run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install linux-mptcp` after that.  I've edited the answer slightly, but you need to read the answer and follow the commands given to you.

Comment: @ThomasW. I read it and created the file myself and saved it.

Comment: @edbale Then you ran `apt-get update` before running the `install` command?

Comment: @ThomasW. I am sorry for troubling you long. Thanks, its working : When I quit nano I just wrote and closed the terminal didn't do Ctrl+X and then Y. Thanks a lot. I will delete the other question.

Comment: @edbale It's just a case of needing to read and *actually follow **all** the steps provided in answers* to get the result you want.  That's all :)